# Ruby - ignore "exit" in code

Tags: ruby, exit

Consider this code:

```
class Bar
  def initialize
    puts 'Hi from class Bar.'
    exit
  end
end


class Foo
  def initialize
    loop {
      case $stdin.gets.chomp
      when 'foo'
        puts 'Hi from class Foo.'
      when 'bar'
        Bar.new
      end
    }
  end
end
```

Can I ignore the exit in class Bar somehow?

It terminates my loop. I don't want that.

Note - the real code base is much larger and more complicated than that. But it boils down to this question whether I can ignore exit() or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
loop {
  begin
    Bar.new
  rescue SystemExit
    p $!  #: #<SystemExit: exit>
  end
}
```

This will print `#<SystemExit: exit>` in an infinite loop, without ever exiting.

Comment: does this prevent the script from exiting?

Comment: @rogerdpack: Yes, it does. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the best solution to handle exits from other code.

Answer (score 2):

One hackish way to define an `exit` method in context:

```
class Bar; def exit; end; end
```

This works because `exit` in the initializer will be resolved as `self.exit`<sup>1</sup>. In addition, this approach allows using the object after it has been created, as in: `b = B.new`.

But really, one *shouldn't* be doing this: don't have `exit` (or even `puts`) there to begin with.

(And why is there an "infinite" loop and/or user input in an intiailizer? This entire problem is primarily the result of poorly structured code.)

---

<sup>1</sup> Remember [Kernel#exit](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-exit) is *only* a method. Since Kernel is included in every Object, then it's merely the case that `exit` normally resolves to `Object#exit`. However, this can be changed by introducing an overridden method as shown - nothing fancy.

Comment: While `exit` can be overridden, *should it* is the real question. I can imagine some nasty bugs down the road for that codebase. Exit has a specific purpose and expected behavior and changing it would be really irritating.

Comment: @theTinMan I agree. A added emphasis to *"shouldn't"* .. at least the behavior is confined to B or a subclass.

Comment: "> don't have exit (or even puts) there to begin with" - What if you are not in control over code written by someone else?

Comment: Interesting solution but not clean - I do not want to redefine exit in my project. I merely want other classes to not exit when they think they should want to do so - I don't want to allow them to exit when they think I should exit. The earlier solution to rescue SystemExit seems clearer and cleaner than redefining or aliasing exit.

Comment: @user722915 You don't need to redefine exit in the project: it is *only* changed in the B class. And I agree it's not "clean", but *this entire problem isn't clean* and the fundamental broken design should be fixed. This is the only way I know of to use the result of the method call/initializer. Catching the exception unwinds the stack, which makes B.new (read: this code) seem like even more of a joke if instances of B are never meant to be used.